# How to test `NavLink` with Mocha from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I would like to test is my `NavLink` has a certain URL:

**Splash.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from '../shared/logo/index';
import * as styles from './style.css';

class Splash extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={styles.indexAppContent}>
        <NavLink to="/home"  className={styles.index}>
          <Logo />
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Splash;
```

**Test**

```
/* eslint-disable object-property-newline */
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';


describe('<Splash />', () => {

  it('Logo links to home', () => {
    expect(wrapperNavLink.prop('to'))
      .equals('/home');
  })

});
```

How can I test the value of rendered href's for react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two way you can test whether pass props are reaching correctly to your component.

**1.Test component in isolation -**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

describe("<NavLink  />", () => {
    it("1.contains correct passed prop", () => {
        const comp = (
            <NavLink to="/home"  className={"test"}>
                NaveLink Test
            </NavLink>
        );
        const wrapper = shallow( comp );
        expect(wrapper.instance().props.to).to.equal("/home");
    });
});
```

**2.Test component as whole e.g component `<Splash />` in your case.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Splash from './splash'; // <----------- import the component you want to test

describe("<Splash  />", () => {
    it("2.contains correct passed prop", () => {
        const comp = (
            <Splash />
        );
        const wrapper = shallow( comp );

        expect(wrapper.find(NavLink).first().props().to).to.equal("/home");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, took me a while to come back to this :) Interesting then. `wrapper.find(NavLink).first().props().to` so you use find by passing it the actual `component` Thanks bud. Is there clear documentation about this that I missed?

Comment: @JamieHutber Your welcome. I think you can look on airbnb enzyme docs,

Comment: I am getting an error  Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>